# Accessing a shared string from another process causes no-error crash

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, shared-memory

I'm attempting to share a string between processes, and it's causing a crash that has no error output. I've created a minimal example that exhibits the behavior:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from ctypes import c_wchar_p
import time
import random

alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

class StringGenerator(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        mp.Process.__init__(self, *args, daemon=True, **kwargs)
        self.sharedString = mp.Value(c_wchar_p, '')

    def run(self):
        print('generator init')
        while True:
            newString = ''.join(random.sample(alphabet, int(random.random()*10+5)))
            self.sharedString.value = newString
            print('generator created string:', newString)
            time.sleep(0.5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    generator = StringGenerator()
    generator.start()

    print('starting')
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.69)
        print('getting string from generator')
        newString = generator.sharedString.value
        print('new string:', newString)
    print('done')
```

Expected output:

```
starting
generator init
generator created string: ftynxoerj
generator created string: wzpjbxsrfa
getting string from generator
new string: wzpjbxsrfa
generator created string: wejfiesl
getting string from generator
new string: wejfiesl
generator created string: eiofjwqa
generator created string: djlsjei
getting string from generator
new string: djlsjei
... etc etc
```

Actual output:

```
starting
generator init
generator created string: cywub
generator created string: vjnwrhgb
getting string from generator
```

And that's it - my interactive DOS prompt comes back, no error message, nothing. The program just terminates. I do notice that in the task manager, there's a zombie python process left running - I'm guessing that's the StringGenerator process still running.

I tried wrapping the get/set of the shared Value in a lock acquire/release system, but it didn't change the behavior at all.

I'm using python 3.8.7 on Windows 10.

Can anyone explain why this is happening, and how I should change this to successfully share a string between processes? Thanks!

Comment: You are sharing only the pointer to the string data. This pointer is only valid for the process in which it was created. Use an "mp.Array" of type "ctypes.c_wchar" instead. It must provide space for at least one more character than the largest string you want to store. The "mp.Array" should have "value" and "raw" attributes to easily set or get the string as a whole.

Comment: @Brionius to share a direct memory address, look into `multiprocessing.shared_memory`, made available in python 3.8

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Michael Butscher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/987358/michael-butscher)'s suggestion, I used a `multiprocessing.Array` object initialized with the `ctypes.c_wchar` and a maximum string length to share the string. I also padded the strings with spaces when copying to the shared array, to make sure the last string was fully replaced. Here is the working code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from ctypes import c_wchar
import time
import random

alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

class StringGenerator(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        mp.Process.__init__(self, *args, daemon=True, **kwargs)
        self.sharedString = mp.Array(c_wchar, 16)

    def run(self):
        print('generator init')
        while True:
            newString = ''.join(random.sample(alphabet, int(random.random()*10+5)))
            self.sharedString[:] = newString + ' '*(16 - len(newString))
            print('generator created string:', newString)
            time.sleep(0.5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    generator = StringGenerator()
    generator.start()

    print('starting')
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.69)
        print('getting string from generator')
        newString = generator.sharedString[:]
        print('new string:', newString)
    print('done')
```

Output:

```
starting
generator init
generator created string: ademxlp
generator created string: wivalymkhsneg
getting string from generator
new string: wivalymkhsneg
generator created string: frbmlwjypenvqa
getting string from generator
new string: frbmlwjypenvqa
generator created string: zdcbof
getting string from generator
new string: zdcbof
generator created string: leuzsmtrghvpfd
generator created string: ijcnquketolx
getting string from generator
new string: ijcnquketolx
generator created string: brtidjqnp
getting string from generator
new string: brtidjqnp
generator created string: zpjobdha
getting string from generator
new string: zpjobdha
generator created string: jpgbhf
...etc etc
```